# AssertionError: asm.js requires -O1 or above

Tags: javascript, emscripten, asm.js

i just started asm.js and stuck at one point. i installed emscripten,clang and node js already and my c program also running fine with emscripten with this command :

> ./emcc hello_world.c
>
> ./emcc hello_world.c -o hello_world.html

but when i am trying to run this file with asm it shows me an insertion error with this command :

> ./emcc -01 -s ASM_JS=1 hello_world.c

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./emcc", line 1219, in <module>
assert opt_level >= 1 or fastcomp, 'asm.js requires -O1 or above
AssertionError: asm.js requires -O1 or above
```

So how to solve this error ?

,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Should be fine when doing

```
./emcc -02 -s ASM_JS=1 hello_world.c
```